# Why $H_{V^* \cup W^*} > H_{V \cup W}$ if $H_V$ denotes entropy of language

Tags: analysis, computer-science, formal-languages, information-theory, entropy

Let $W \subseteq X^*$ be an infinite language over a finite alphabet $X$, and define ($|w|$ denotes the length of $w \in W$)
$$
 H_W := \limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log_{|X|} | \{ w \in w \in W, |w| = n \} |}{n}
$$
the entropy of the language. Then of course if $U \subseteq V$ for two languages we have $H_U \le H_V$ as $V$ has at least at many words as $U$ of each length. But if $H_{V^*} > H_V$ and $H_{W^*} > H_W$, why do we have
$$
 H_{V^* \cup W^*} > H_{V \cup W}
$$
where $V^*$ denotes the Kleen-star $V^* := \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} V^n$.

Comment: If V* denotes the Kleene star, then isn't V a subset of V* and W a subset of W* (so H_V* > H_V and H_W* > H_W hold automatically)? In this case, it's also true that V U W is a subset of V* U W* so again H_{V* U W*} > H_{V U W}. (Maybe * does not stand for Kleene star?)

Comment: $U\subseteq V$ just implies $H_U \le H_V$, not strict inequality, but I need it strict here (of course $H_{V^*\cup W^*} \ge H_{V\cup w}$ is obvious).